# Why won't my XML schema pick up the errors?

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

My schema wont pick up the errors in my data, is there a glaring reason? Please see below, essentially for the restrictions I created it should come up with errors when other information has been given, but that is not the case with mine. It just appears valid. Here I applied a restriction using type string and ennumerating it. It should throw validation errors because the spelling is incorrect in some places.

```
Shorten version: 

<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="Midterm">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="StudentData" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Gnumber"/>
                            <xs:element type="xs:string" **name="ResidenceStatus"/>
                            **<xs:simpletype>
                                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                    <xs:enumeration value="In-state"/>
                                    <xs:enumeration value="Out-of-state"/>
                                </xs:restriction>
                            </xs:simpletype>****
                            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="FirstName"/>
                            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="MiddleInitial"/>
                            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="LastName"/>
                            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="DOB"/>
                            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="ProgramName"/>
                            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Concentration"/>
                            <xs:element type="xs:float" name="StartYear"/>
                            <xs:element name="course">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Department"/>
                                        <xs:element type="xs:float" name="CatalogNumber"/>
                                        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Semester"/>
                                        <xs:element type="xs:float" name="Year"/>
                                        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="LetterGrade"/>
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

XML DATA

```
<Midterm>
    <StudentData>
        <Gnumber>   G12654312   </Gnumber>
        <ResidenceStatus>   In-state    </ResidenceStatus>
        <FirstName> ALBERTO </FirstName>
        <MiddleInitial> L   </MiddleInitial>
        <LastName>  SMITH   </LastName>
        <DOB>   2/3/1981    </DOB>
        <ProgramName>   MS Health Informatics   </ProgramName>
        <Concentration> Data analytics  </Concentration>
        <StartYear> 2014    </StartYear>
        <course> 
            <Department>    HAP </Department>
            <CatalogNumber> 463 </CatalogNumber>
            <Semester>  SPRING  </Semester>
            <Year>  2014    </Year>
            <LetterGrade>   B+  </LetterGrade>
        </course>
    </StudentData>
</Midterm>
```

Comment: Well, your XSD is incomplete and you haven't shared the relevant XML. So this question does not provide a [mcve] - which is mandatory for this kind of question.

Comment: Also, how are you validating your xml with the schema?

Comment: @DanielHaley I am validating it against my xml data, both which say have correct syntax. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @zx485 is there a way to attach the xml? I was getting errors that this was too much code to begin with

Comment: You absolutely have to include your XML when asking others for help, but you have to prune down your XML and XSD to a reasonably small set that still exhibits the problem.  See [mcve].   Often the process of creating an MCVE reveals the problem directly even.

Comment: No I meant what tool/code are you using to actually perform the validation. Xerces in Java? Xmllint?

Comment: @DanielHaley using the xml tools plugin to validate, "validate now"

Comment: What @DanielHaley asks is important. Yesterday I had the same issue like you: an XSD-1.1 file which validated an XML, but really shouldn't have.

Comment: @kjhughes apologies, I've made the corrections. I also pruned it down to only one restriction in place, while maintaining the structure of the xsd

Comment: I strongly suspect that the problem is not in the XML or XSD code, but in the way you are attempting to perform the validation.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to validate your sample XML with the XSD, it threw some errors, so I couldn't reproduce your problem, but only fix the errors of your XSD. I used the command

```
xmlstarlet val --err --xsd source.xsd input.xml
```

to validate your XSD. XSD-1.0 seemed to suffice to validate it, so no XSD-1.1 processor was necessary.

---

One of the problems of your source XML seemed to be the leading and trailing spaces of the value of `ResidenceStatus`.

Applying your XSD to the XML lead to errors until I fixed the definition of `ResidenceStatus`. So far, I cannot tell if this occurs due to your XSD processor.

But you can try to fix the definition to

```
<xs:element name="ResidenceStatus">
  <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base="normalized">
        <xs:enumeration value="In-state"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="Out-of-state"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

and add the type definition of `normalized` at the end of the root level of your `xs:schema`:

```
<xs:simpleType name="normalized">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:whiteSpace value="collapse"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

This `simpleType` named `normalized` will remove leading and trailing spaces of the element's value, so that the enumeration will match.

P.S.: your XSD had a typo:
`<xs:simpletype>` of `ResidenceStatus` should have been `<xs:simpleType>`.